# Using Facebook Open Stream API with PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I'm interested in using the Facebook Open Stream API to read a users Facebook news feed in my PHP web app.

I'm interested if someone with API experience can answer the following;

1. Am I right to use Facebook Open Stream API?
2. Where is the most comprehensive documentation.
3. Is there a PHP library I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the new Facebook graph API.

Here's the docs for it: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api

Here's their PHP SDK: http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/